# Best scenario for calculating multiple dates from array ? - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, datetime

I have array of items like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0:16:0
    [1] => 0:0:8
    [2] => 0:5:0
    ...
    [n] => 0:3:1
)
```

There could be more arrays, they are symbolize
hours, minutes, seconds.
How can I calculate 0 + 1 + 2 + ... + n and to get final number of hours, minutes and seconds?

Comment: As you try to do it now?

Comment: Please share some code and a specific issue you are facing we are not here to code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code out

```
$arr = array('0:16:0', '25:12:5', '0:0:10', '0:5:0');

// converting all the times to seconds
$t_seconds = 0;
foreach ($arr as $v) {
    sscanf($v, "%d:%d:%d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
    $t_seconds += $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds;
}

// condition if seconds calculated are negative
$sign = ($t_seconds < 0 ? '-' : '');
$t_seconds = abs($t_seconds);

// converting seconds, taking care of wrong minutes/seconds formats like 02:63:65
$hours = floor($t_seconds / 3600);
$minutes = floor(($t_seconds / 60) % 60);
$seconds = $t_seconds % 60;

// final format
$sum = $sign . sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
```

Result ($sum variable)

```
25:33:15
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved by seperating hours, minutes, secounds as array from my foreach element. Then i call array, using array_sum 
***( thanks Rizier123 for point me on that function )***

```
// receive values and calculate with current hours
        $finalHourPause = array_sum($pauseArrayHours) . "\n";
        $finalMinutePause = array_sum($pauseArrayMinutes) . "\n";
        $finalSecoundsPause = array_sum($pauseArraySecounds) . "\n";
```